# How to clear all the previously drawn graphics in vc++ paint?

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, picturebox

I have drawn rectangles in picture box using paint event. When i click clear button. i want the graphics to vanish. i call paint event everytime the mouse moves. What should i do?

Code in paint event:

```
Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;
float PenWidth = 2;
if(msdwnflag!=-1 && count%2==1)
{
    if(selecflag==0)
    {
    g->DrawRectangle( gcnew Pen( Color::Blue,PenWidth ), RcDraw);
}
else
{
    RcDraw.Width = finalMousePos.X- RcDraw.X;
    RcDraw.Height = finalMousePos.Y- RcDraw.Y;
    g->DrawRectangle( gcnew Pen( Color::Red,PenWidth ), RcDraw);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `pb` is your `PictureBox` then clear its image to clear all the graphics. Also, You can use a variable (`buttonpressed`) to check whether it is true (button clear pressed) or false (otherwise)

```
     buttonpressed=1;
     pb->Image = nullptr;
     pb->Refresh();
```

In your paint method include all the graphics if Not buttonpressed:

```
     if (buttonpressed != 1){
         // all your graphics code
     }
```

When you want the graphics to appear back when you press a button change the `buttonpressed` value:

```
    buttonpressed=0;
    pb->Refresh();
```

Comment: You can renew the `buttonpressed=0` from 1 when you want the graphics to appear. So you take out the else part of the statement. Also see that `picturebox` is refreshed after updating the value of buttonpressed.

Comment: Please note that I moved the variable assignment to the top. Please post your updated code. The above codes needs to be entered in 3 different methods and I have mentioned where. You should post all your methods with method definition instead of just a few lines of codes from paint method if it doesn't work. Even if you enter the first two blocks of code in the two methods I have mentioned, it should work.

Comment: Just as a curiosity how do you call the paint method every-time the mouse moves? Using `refresh()` method? Also, I don't see the need to call the refresh everytime with your mouse move. It is poor design.

Comment: @subs- i call picturebox->invalidate(); in mouse move event. fine?

Comment: @PrasannaRN a bit different than `refresh()`: According to MSDN, -`refresh()` -> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls. I prefer `refresh()`

Comment: u can use update() also for that
but it worked without them for me.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a graphics of the transparent colour. thats wat i finally did. not a gud design but works :)

Comment: @CodingMash: why is this not an answer to the question? IMHO, the OP did exactly the right thing by sharing his solution, using an answer (which is what they're for).